How to restrict "Allow Azure services and resources to access this server" to services from my subscription only?
In Azure SQL Server, there is an option called "Allow Azure services and resources to access this server". However, enabling this option allows access from all Azure services, including those belonging to other customers.
I want to ensure that only my Azure services and resources can access my SQL Server, without exposing it to potential access from other customers. How can this restriction be implemented?

According to the MS document

When Allow Azure services and resources to access this server is enabled, your server allows communications from all resources inside the Azure boundary, regardless of whether they are part of your subscription. Behind the scenes, a special server-level firewall rule is added that starts and ends with IP address of 0.0.0.0.

If you want to restrict access of users who are out of subscription, you can use private access for SQL server instead of using public access.

Create private Endpoint and use it, for information you can refer to the MS Document.
